# How to zoom in and out without a mouse wheel in the shader editor?

Tags: modeling

[image]

As the picture shows, I want to zoom in and out to navigate around in the shader editor, and since I am using a Wacom stylus, there is no mouse wheel to use, so I enabled the "emulating the third mouse button"(may not spell in this way exactly in the Preference).

However, the emulation does not seem to work in the shader editor, although it works in the 3d view.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what tablet do you have or how did you configure your Wacome, but i use mine and configurated one button as middle click and i can use it by holding down CTRL + Middle Click (on the stylus) and move to zoom in and out. No third button emulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>middle click</kbd> to zoom in and out. If your tablet uses standard stylus buttons, the front button should be middle click and the back one right click (front being the pen tip). Hope that helps!

EDIT

Apparently, on a mac, holding the <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys and dragging in an out zooms in and out.

I am a linux user, so thanks for letting me know, Xinyu Bao.

If this answer was helpful, please press the up arrow. If the answer solved your question, press the checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for addressing on this. I tried to zoom in and out by holding Option and Command at the same time while drag in and out with my stylus, and it works!

Comment: Awesome! If this solved your question, please click the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone who contributed to this question.

As I had experimented, I found that I can just press Option (Alt in Windows) to simulate the middle mouse key in the shader editor too. So **press the Option and Command** will do the trick.